# Configuring jquery plugins - Script error - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

There are about 10 jquery plugins here *(In the project-Asp.Net MVC & JQuery)* , there is something causing errors and conflicts
in one of the plugins [jcarousel](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel)

**1st** I got an error mentioned In the below lines :

**Location :**

```
 isVisible = this._visible.index(curr) >= 0;
```

Using the Error console found this error

```
Timestamp: 5/24/2013 7:08:21 PM
Error: TypeError: this._visible.index is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:1884/Scripts/jcarousel/jquery.jcarousel.js
Line: 826
```

**Cause :** I found "_visible" is null

---

**2nd**

I changed `this._visible.index(curr) >= 0;` to `true` to pass this error

```
isVisible = true
//this._visible.index(curr) >= 0;
```

Here the error is passed and next error happens :

**Location :**

```
    return this.items().index(item);
```

**Error :**

```
Timestamp: 5/24/2013 7:24:03 PM
Error: TypeError: this.items(...).index is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:1884/Scripts/jcarousel/jquery.jcarousel.js
Line: 372
```

The Line  return `this.items().index(item);` is hit several times but putting a breakpoint in the below line of that never fired.

---

**Conclusion**

1. As a guess it could be a conflict in this file maybe the word "index",
2. This is used by Asp.Net MVC Inside a section and partial pages, not sure but want to know could it cause something like this. (Less Probable cause it's rendered exactly the same as it's equivalent `Asp.Net Forms` version, Just wanted to mention the way I used)
3. Any other ideas what is the cause and how to solve it ?

---

- *In my Asp.net Forms project I configured the plugins to work correctly.*
- *Other plugins registered before this plugin were working correctly.*
- *After disabling the call to the jcarousel everything works fine.*

Comment: Make sure jquery is loaded first. Then figure out what exactly `this` is. `I found "_visible" is null` is a good indication of where to start looking for problems -- with your `this` object. Forcing `true` is just ignoring previous problems in the script.

Comment: @Jason JQuery is the top in the scripts bundle list, and as I said other plugins before the plugin I mentioned were working correctly, I changed it into "true" to be sure of the problem and finding next clues, And I think it was helpful to be more stressed on that line and what is in.

Comment: @Jasen also please mention what do you think I should look over "this" object? also I said to name of the plugin if it could be handy to find what could be a good change. thanks

Comment: You'd have to share an example that demonstrates your error to get more specific and useful help.

Comment: The files are bigger than to be shared, I tried to isolate the error and it's related parts and mentioned here, The code of the plugin is here : https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel, I have to go now, but after returning here if I could add any other helpful info will do that

Comment: Put the minimal amount of HTML into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) along with the the necessary script libraries and setup a jcarousel object to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trials I became sure the problem is from the jcarousel itself,
It had incompatibility issues with it's prior versions. downgrading of it from it's latest beta version solved the problem.